# Parent Div does not adjust height when adding div dynamically

Tags: html, css

I am adding divs dynamically as shown in http://jsfiddle.net/Lijo/ZkLg6/5/.

The parent #mainHolder div is not increasing its width when child elements are added – as a result the children breaks the parent div. How can we overcome this by adjusting the parent div height?

[image]

**jQuery**

```
$('input').click(function()
{
 var existingDirectChildrenDivCount = $('#mainHolder > div').size();



 if( existingDirectChildrenDivCount % 3 == 0)
 {
      $('#mainHolder').append ("<div class='firstDiv'> A  </div>")
 }

 if( existingDirectChildrenDivCount % 3 == 1)
 {
      $('#mainHolder').append ("<div class='secondDiv'> B </div>")
 }

 if( existingDirectChildrenDivCount % 3 == 2)
 {
      $('#mainHolder').append ("<div class='thirdDiv'> C  </div>")
 }
```

}
   );

**HTML**

```
<html>

   <input type="submit" value="Add" />
   <br/>   
   <div id="mainHolder">
   S    
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.4.1.js"></script>

</html>
```

**CSS**

```
#mainHolder
{
    width: 400px;
    border-top: 3px solid orange;
    border-bottom: 3px solid red;
    border-left: 3px solid purple;
    border-right: 3px solid pink;
    height:auto;
}

.firstDiv
{
    float: left;
    display: inline;
    background-color: #f5B5f5;
    height:100px;
}

.secondDiv
{
    float: left;
    display: inline;
    background-color: #FF007F;
    height:100px;
}

.thirdDiv
{
    float: left;
    display: inline;
    background-color: Pink;
    height:100px;
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Add overflow:auto

```
#mainHolder
{
    width: 400px;
    border-top: 3px solid orange;
    border-bottom: 3px solid red;
    border-left: 3px solid purple;
    border-right: 3px solid pink;
    height:auto; overflow:auto
}
```

Demo here http://jsfiddle.net/ZkLg6/11/

Comment: +1 for your nice answer we can give overflow:hidden; because its supports Mac computer's also overflow:auto; doesnt support.

Comment: yes @Sowymya i was just expressing my views for overflow:hidden; :-)

Answer (score 2):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/ZkLg6/7/

The fix is to use a div that clears floated elements. I had to push your dynamic elements into a nested div inside mainHolder to ensure the `clear` div was always below them but it works well.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add overflow: auto; to the CSS of #mainHolder.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to add a  at the end of your #mainHolder and insert elements before that (or just keep removing and re-adding it every time you add a new div. This is because you're using floats, alternatively if you can drop the float from the other divs everything should work as expected. The overflow: auto; solution is also good and seems simpler.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
#mainHolder
{
    min-width: 400px;
    float:left;
    border-top: 3px solid orange;
    border-bottom: 3px solid red;
    border-left: 3px solid purple;
    border-right: 3px solid pink;
    height:20px;
}
```

The only problem here is letter "S",but you may put it inside some div. Like those colored. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZkLg6/9/) is updated JS fiddle.

Hm. But that works if you want to increase WIDTH, not HEIGHT. If you want to increase height - just add overflow:hidden; Plus there are some more changes in your css. Take a look at [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZkLg6/15/)

Answer (score 0):

You have to clear the floating. You can do that inserting an element like br which has clear:both.

Here is a piece of code you can add in order to work:

```
$('#mainHolder').find("br").remove(); // remove already added br
$("<br>").css({clear : "both"}).appendTo($('#mainHolder')); // append a br after the last element.
```

I've updated your jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZkLg6/13/

Answer (score 0):

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/ZkLg6/19/
I used `overflow:hidden`

```
#mainHolder
{
width: 400px;
border-top: 3px solid orange;
border-bottom: 3px solid red;
border-left: 3px solid purple;
border-right: 3px solid pink;
height:auto; overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Set both overflow and height to auto, and now the parent div's offsetHeight will update dynamically!